# Cosmological constant of $\text{AdS}_5 \times S^5$

Tags: general-relativity, action, cosmological-constant, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I have a quick question about the Einstein-Hilbert action $S_{\text{EH}}$ action with cosmological constant regarding $\text{AdS}_5 \times S^5$ spacetime. $S_{\text{EH}}$ is given by

$$S_{\text{EH}} = \frac{1}{16 \pi G_{10}} \int\limits_{\mathcal{M}}(\mathcal{R} - 2 \Lambda_{10}) \sqrt{|g_{10}|} \text{d}^{10} x.$$

For $\text{AdS}_5 \times S^5$ spacetime, the Ricci scalar is given by

$$\mathcal{R} = R_{\text{AdS}_5} + R_{S^5}.$$

Since

$$R_{\text{AdS}_5} = -R_{S^5} = -\frac{n(n - 1)}{L^2},$$

where $n$ is the dimension of our spacetime and $L$ is the curvature radius, then $\mathcal{R} = 0$. My question is whether

$$\Lambda_{10} \stackrel{?}{=} \Lambda_{\text{AdS}_5} + \Lambda_{S^5}$$

is true. If so, since

$$\Lambda_{\text{AdS}_5} = -\Lambda_{S^5} = -\frac{(n - 1)(n - 2)}{2L^2},$$

wouldn't that mean that the contribution of the cosmological constant in $S_{\text{EH}}$ is null too? Does that mean that $S_{\text{EH}} = 0$ for $\text{AdS}_5 \times S^5$ spacetime?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When people talk about $AdS_5\times S^5$ they usually mean specific solution, the *Freund–Rubin vacuum* (see [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(80)90590-0)), of 10-dimensional supergravity. It does not have cosmological constant but does have *form field* with flux on the $S^5$. Without form field $AdS_5\times S^5$ is not a solution of  Λ-vacuum Einstein's field equations.

Comment: Understood. I'll check out the reference you recommended. Thank you.